# Adding a Product List on Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, shopify-template

I am using the `minimal template` in `Shopify` and would like to recreate this image attached. I have tried researching for similar examples but can't seem to find anything. How do I go about creating this image? How do I get an image behind a menu?

[image: Trying to Create]

Any links or documents to achieving image would really help.

Comment: are you find this image [Image url](https://www.llialighting.com/Content/files/ProductImages/v_06f3_angled448253599.png)

Comment: You need to study about [aspect ratios](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008538927-Understanding-aspect-ratios).

Comment: @MohitGupta yes that is the image, but how would I go about adding the product list ontop of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to break down the design to work out it's constituent parts. You want a background image and an overlay with product cards. You want to position the overlay on top of the picture you do this by applying position:relative to the parent and position:absolute to the child so it will be positioned within it's parent. Then apply transform: translate() to translate the overlay dependant on it's size to achieve the offset on the right hand side.

Here's a pen : https://codepen.io/NeilWkz/pen/qgRMyW

```
<div class="img-hero-with-menu-overlay">
 <div class="left-img">
  </div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="product-card">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/150/" alt="">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Product 1</h3>
        <p>lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-card">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/150/" alt="">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Product 2</h3>
        <p>lorem</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-card">
      <img src="https://lorempixel.com/300/150/" alt="">
      <div class="info">
        <h3>Product 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
img-hero-with-menu-overlay {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #bcbdc0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.left-img {
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  width: 75%;
  background: url("https://www.llialighting.com/Content/files/ProductImages/v_06f3_angled448253599.png")
    no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-12.5%, -50%);
  width: 40%;
}

.product-card {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.info {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: this is perfect thanks. But now its adding a huge grey space after the picture. How do I remove that?

Comment: The grey space is on you design. I've updated the codepen and answer above to move the background color from the body to the hero module.